# Асинхронный запрос с развращаемыми данными

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Дело обстоит так. 
Необходимо вернуть данные из асинхронного запроса. Само самой работает как нужно если установить `async : false`. Но необходимо именно асинхронно. Реализую загрузку файлов, необходимо получить ссылку на изображение и сохранить в объекте, поэтому это необходимо. Ниже пример как пытался сделать

```
function foo() {
    var result = false;
    var callback = function(data) { result = return }
    $.ajax({
        /*Не значимая часть*/
        success: function(resp) {callback(resp)},
    )};
    return result;
}
```

Comment: зачем же вы их развращаете :(

Comment: @teran главное, что бы данные были совершеннолетними :)

Comment: Ваша функция в любом случае должна дождаться пока придут данные, что бы их вернуть. что она вернет вызвавшему, если от ajax данные еще не пришли ? возможно стоит подумать над тем, что бы вызывающий код в эту функцию отдал свой callback, который надо вызвать когда данные будут доступны

Comment: Лучше бы вы доярку развратили...

Answer (score 1):

Просто вызываете из `success` функцию в которой будет логика продолжения.

```
function foo() {

    $.ajax({
        success: function(resp) {
          result = true;
          doNext(result);
        },
    )};

}

function doNext(value) {
   // some logic
}
```

Есть и другой подход, основанный на новой в JavaScript функции `fetch`.

Она возвращает промисы, и из промисов можно делать цепочки.

Документация по `fetch` - https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Пример из документации

```
fetch('flowers.jpg', myInit)
  .then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(myBlob) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  myImage.src = objectURL;
});
```

Как мы видим здесь присутствует цепочка обработчиков запроса, следующий вызывается после завершения предыдущего.